# GXT ContentPanel not resizing when window is resized

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am not able to make a contentpanel resize when the browser is resized. The below code renders the content panel to fill the screen(desired) but doesnt resize when the browser window size is changed.

Code:

```
 public void onModuleLoad() {
     RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
     Viewport viewPort = new Viewport();
     final Layout layout = new FitLayout();
     ContentPanel resultPanel = new ContentPanel();
     resultPanel.setHeading("Result");
     resultPanel.setFrame(true);
     resultPanel.setLayout(layout);
     resultPanel.setScrollMode(Scroll.ALWAYS);
     resultPanel.addButton(new Button("OK"));
     resultPanel.setWidth("100%");
     LayoutContainer page = new LayoutContainer(new RowLayout(Orientation.VERTICAL));
     page.add(resultPanel, new com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.RowData(1, -1));
     viewPort.add(page);

     rootPanel.add(viewPort);
     page.layout();

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewport needs a fitlayout as well:

```
viewPort.setLayout(new FitLayout());
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Upvoted and accepted. Im really struggling to understand the concepts of the different layouts.Would you happen to know any link/article which help me understand Layouts in GXT?

Comment: IF starting a new project, use GXT 3 instead of two, and check out the guides at http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/ - there are several specific to understanding the problem of layouts. They apply somewhat to GXT 2, but 3 is the current version and has been for over a year.